# Why is my grammar does not produce Entry and Exit listener rules for all the rules in the grammar?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have following antlr grammar:

```
grammar LuahTest;

luahtest: (Interval Rotation) | (Rotation Interval);

fragment DATE: INT2 SEP INT2 SEP (INT2 | INT4);
fragment DATES: DATE (DATESEP DATE)+;
fragment DATESPAN: '(' DATE DATESEP DATE ')';

Interval: 'Dates:' DATESPAN;
Rotation : 'Rotation:' 'ONE' | 'ALL';

INT : [0-9];
INT2  : INT INT;
INT4  : INT INT INT INT;
SEP : ('/' | '\\');
DATESEP : ((' ')+ | ',' | '-');
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Running antlr tool against it:

```
java -jar {dir}\antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp -visitor -o {diroutput} LuahTest.g4
```

produces following listener, comments removed for brevity

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("ANTLR", "4.13.1")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
[System.CLSCompliant(false)]
public partial class LuahTestBaseListener : ILuahTestListener {
    public virtual void EnterLuahtest([NotNull] LuahTestParser.LuahtestContext context) { }
    public virtual void EnterEveryRule([NotNull] ParserRuleContext context) { }
    public virtual void ExitEveryRule([NotNull] ParserRuleContext context) { }
    public virtual void VisitTerminal([NotNull] ITerminalNode node) { }
    public virtual void VisitErrorNode([NotNull] IErrorNode node) { }
}
```

My questions are:

- Why "Entry" and "Exit" methods are not generated for "Interval" and "Rotation" rules?
- What and where should I change for these rules to be generated?
- I can't find the chapter in the Antlr reference book to read more about it,I'll appreciate ut if you can point me to these areas in the book.

Thanks!

Comment: Enter and Exit methods are generated only for parsers, not lexers. Interval and Rotation are lexer rules (which appear in your combined lexer/parser grammar). There is no parse tree for lexer rules. It is a leaf node in a parse tree. Change the name of the two symbols to lowercase first letter if you need Enter and Exit defined.